# LinqPad C# get only the 'main' record, not the related ones

Tags: linq-to-entities, linqpad

Using LinqPad 5, I have a database with tables Order and OrderLines, and if i'm using LinqPad using the language c# program, and have something like:

```
var order = Orders.Where(o => o.Id = 123).FirstOrDefault();
```

If I dump the orders i get also the OrderLines back.
If I only want the Order records, in LinqPad, now i need to do something like:

```
var order = Orders.Select(o => new { o.Id, o.Description, o.Code}.Where(o => o.Id = 123).FirstOrDefault();
```

But if the Order table has a lot of columns, I have to mention them all (don't want that).

Is there some way to get only the 'main' record? It should work with '.AsNoTracking()' on the context, but I cannot find this option in LinqPad (have to access the DataContext).
Or maybe do something with lazy loading.

Comment: `OrderLines` isn't in your question. What is it? Where is it? How is it being included? What is the issue with it being included?

Comment: The related entities, such as OrderLines, should appear as hyperlinks. Are you seeing hyperlinks or are the related entities being automatically expanded?